# MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification when video fails

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to make a difference when the `MPMoviePlayerController` ends playing because of en error or when the video just ends. I use the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` that I handle like this

```
- (void)moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *notificationUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *resultValue = notificationUserInfo[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    MPMovieFinishReason reason = (MPMovieFinishReason) [resultValue intValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
        NSLog(@"playback failed without any given reason");

    }
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        NSLog(@"playback ended");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `MPMovieFinishReason` is `MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded` even if the video fails.

When my video fails, I noticed that there is the `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification` being posted just before the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`. It contains this user info

```
{
    AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey = "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo=0x78f621c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x794f3a30 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -12551.)\", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12551)}";
}
```

I could use it as a workaround so set a state in my controller to e.g. `self.failedToPlayToEnd = YES;` and then use it in my `moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish` method. It does not seem right thoug because nothing guarantees me the order of those two notifications.

So the question is, how can I determine that a video failed to play. Btw, I'm talking about when the playback fails not when it stalls.

[Here is the video](http://haignet.co.uk/html5-video-element-test.mp4) that fails 2 seconds before its end